K8 master node CreatePodSandbox for pod failed
I have a k8 practice cluster that I set up on a plain machine. I am having issues with the master node. Firstly, there was no kubelet.service and kubelet.service.d in the /etc/systemd/system directory - I created links from /lib/systemd/system to them and it got a bit better. At least kubelet is running on the port 6443 without crashing, but it is insecure because the cert is not public that kubeadm init makes:
 curl --insecure https://10.0.23.87:6443
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {},
  "code": 403
}

But then kubectl is coming back with back-off crashes:
Nov 15 17:50:00 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: I1115 17:50:00.918250    1032 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="48022387cb1c2e671733ef12decc0e581fd6654b38e80c726dc2c914d9d23390"
Nov 15 17:50:00 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: E1115 17:50:00.918451    1032 pod_workers.go:1301] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-flannel\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=>
Nov 15 17:50:05 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: E1115 17:50:05.028937    1032 log.go:32] "RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox \"f7475b86099fccfacd614fcb781dde9caf4ac04cb9>
Nov 15 17:50:05 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: E1115 17:50:05.029017    1032 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:72] "Failed to create sandbox for pod" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox \"f7475b86099fccfacd614fcb781dde9caf4>
Nov 15 17:50:05 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: E1115 17:50:05.029049    1032 kuberuntime_manager.go:1170] "CreatePodSandbox for pod failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox \"f7475b86099fccfacd614fcb781dde9caf>
Nov 15 17:50:05 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: E1115 17:50:05.029109    1032 pod_workers.go:1301] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"CreatePodSandbox\" for \"coredns-7c65d6cfc9-5l67k_kube-system(c73362ad-a2f3-4e46-bfa9-a742a3d94f24)\" wit>
Nov 15 17:50:06 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: I1115 17:50:06.917942    1032 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="f6d7b4388986d0bc5895b158bb4ee976baf0c8d80b3a7ea7521d9c5288769f22"
Nov 15 17:50:06 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: E1115 17:50:06.918140    1032 pod_workers.go:1301] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-controller-manager\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 5m0s restarting failed>
Nov 15 17:50:11 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: I1115 17:50:11.918298    1032 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="48022387cb1c2e671733ef12decc0e581fd6654b38e80c726dc2c914d9d23390"
Nov 15 17:50:11 ip-10-0-23-87 kubelet[1032]: E1115 17:50:11.918516    1032 pod_workers.go:1301] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"StartContainer\" for \"kube-flannel\" with CrashLoopBackOff: \"back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=>
lines 1-23/23 (END)

What I have noticed, is that docker has no containers:
ubuntu@ip-10-0-23-87:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

Does anybody have an idea where to dig?

This issue seems to have several layers that need to be addressed in order to identify the root cause. It could be related to Kubernetes initialisation, Docker setup, networking, or authentication.
Can you confirm that kubeadm init completed successfully and there were no errors during the initialization process?
Is Docker running on your node? Can you confirm the Docker status with systemctl status docker and check if there are any issues with Docker itself?
Can you run docker info to check for any warnings or issues related to Docker's configuration?
When running docker ps -a, does it show any containers, or is it returning empty, indicating that no containers are being started by Docker?
Is the Flannel CNI plugin applied correctly to your cluster? Can you confirm that the Flannel pods are running by checking kubectl get pods -n kube-system?
If the Flannel pod is failing to start, can you check the pod logsfor any errors related to networking?
Have you checked the kubelet logs for any errors related to starting or managing containers?  journalctl -u kubelet -f
Are you seeing any specific errors related to pod sandbox creation or network setup in the kubelet logs ?
Can you confirm that the certificates generated by kubeadm init were correctly created and placed in the /etc/kubernetes/pki directory?
Are you able to reach the Kubernetes API server (https://:6443) without receiving a "403 Forbidden" error, and have you configured kubelet to authenticate properly with the API server?
